# How to SQL PIVOT this data by day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

With the following schema and table, showing example output of the table, I'm trying to "PIVOT" this data to have rows consisting of the SERIAL and AREA, with each column being the COMPLIANCE for each "NIGHTOF" record. Ideal output shown below as well. I can not wrap my head around the PIVOT syntax no matter how many times I read examples...

Schema and table:

```
SELECT [CONTID], [AREA], [NIGHTOF], [COMPLIANCE] FROM ComplianceScores
```

Regular Output:

```
CONTID  NIGHTOF     AREA    COMPLIANCE
001     2014-01-01  Room 2  28
001     2014-01-01  Room 2  18
001     2014-01-01  Room 2  20
003     2014-01-02  Room 1  18
003     2014-01-02  Room 1  70
003     2014-01-02  Room 1  80
008     2014-01-03  Room 1  0
009     2014-01-04  Room 1  35
```

Ideal output:

```
CONTID  AREA    2014-01-01   2014-01-02    2014-01-03
001     Room 2  28           18            20
003     Room 1  18           70            80
```

Comment: How many days/columns do you need to support?  Note that your output will become hard to read for more than a few days.

Comment: Also, your data and output don't match.   001 Room 2 has 3 entries for 1/1.   What does the expected output mean?  Highest of the 3?  Sum of the entries?   Not very clear, it would help if you made the output match the data

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Sparky that your data and output don't match.

I think your data was meant to be like:

```
create table ComplianceScores (
  CONTID char(3),
  NIGHTOF date,
  AREA varchar(10),
  COMPLIANCE int
  )

insert ComplianceScores (CONTID, NIGHTOF, AREA, COMPLIANCE)
values ('001', '2014-01-01', 'Room 2', 28)
, ('001', '2014-01-02', 'Room 2', 18)
, ('001', '2014-01-03', 'Room 2', 20)
, ('003', '2014-01-01', 'Room 1', 18)
, ('003', '2014-01-02', 'Room 1', 70)
, ('003', '2014-01-03', 'Room 1', 80)
```

And I think you're looking for this SQL:

```
select ContId, Area, [2014-01-01], [2014-01-02], [2014-01-03]  
  from (select Area, ContId, NightOf, Compliance
          from ComplianceScores) SourceTable  
pivot
(  
  sum(Compliance)  
  for NightOf in ([2014-01-01], [2014-01-02], [2014-01-03])  
) pt;
```